# ffmpeg cut, encode MKV to MP4, and burn subtitles

Tags: windows, ffmpeg, mp4, subtitles, matroska

**I want to cut a section of an MKV and encode it to MP4, while also burning the subtitles.**
But I don't know how to do that all in 1 pass ([related question](https://superuser.com/questions/1118761/ffmpeg-burn-subtitles-while-cutting-video)), so I tried it step by step.

- When I first cut the MKV, and then encode it to MP4, it won't hardcode the subtitles. The cut MKV container still retained the subtitles. I tried both internal and external subtitles.

  - test 1 (fail):  subtitles directly from MKV
    `ffmpeg -i konosuba.mkv -ss 180 -t 30 test.mkv`
    `ffmpeg -i test.mkv -vf subtitles=test.mkv test2.mp4`
  - test 2 (fail): external subtitles
    `ffmpeg -i konosuba.mkv -ss 180 -t 30 test.mkv`
    `ffmpeg -i test.mkv -map 0:s:0 subs.ass`
    `ffmpeg -i test.mkv -vf subtitles=subs.ass test2.mp4`
- It succesfully hardcodes the subtitles when I first encode the whole MKV to MP4, afterwards I can cut it. But this takes much longer with big source files :(

  - test 3 (success)
    `ffmpeg -i konosuba.mkv -vf subtitles=konosuba.mkv test.mp4`
    `ffmpeg -i test.mp4 -ss 180 -t 30 test2.mp4`

There seems to be a difference in the logs: **[test 1](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/d2eb6f09fabba88afe86bd4607b048a4#file-test-1-fail-L143-L144) vs [test 3](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/d2eb6f09fabba88afe86bd4607b048a4#file-test-3-success-L130-L133)**

Am I doing something wrong here? I really don't understand why I can't burn subtitles, unless when encoding the original MKV container without cutting it.

**Edit:** Just trying to burn subtitles by itself doesn't seem to work for me [(log)](https://gist.github.com/anonymous/d9b37b7992ccfe81959910267ba25cd9)
`ffmpeg -i test2.mp4 -vf subtitles=subs.ass test3.mp4`

---

Log: **https://gist.github.com/anonymous/d2eb6f09fabba88afe86bd4607b048a4**
Build: https://ffmpeg.zeranoe.com/builds/
OS: Windows 10 v1607

https://trac.ffmpeg.org/wiki/HowToBurnSubtitlesIntoVideo
https://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg-filters.html#subtitles-1

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just combine the two commands of test3:

```
ffmpeg -i konosuba.mkv -ss 180 -t 30 -vf subtitles=konosuba.mkv test.mp4
```